# How to test web application using QTP?

Tags: qtp

I am new in QTP.

I need to test Web application using QTP.For study purpose I used Gmail login page,Using below Script

```
Systemutil.Run "http://www.gmail.com"
Browser("Title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").WebEdit("name:=Email").Set "xxxxxx"
Browser("Title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").WebEdit("name:=Passwd").Set "yyyyyy"
Browser("Title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").WebButton("name:=Sign in").click
```

After Gmail page open nothing happening at last geeting one error also

```
Cannot find the "[ WebEdit ]" object's parent "[ Browser ]" (class Browser). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Line (2): "Browser("Title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").WebEdit("name:=Email").Set "xxxxxx"". 

Tip: If the objects in your application have changed, the Maintenance Run Mode can 
help you identify and update your steps and/or the objects in your repository.
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using descriptive programming everywhere for learning purposes. I strongly suggest you don't write actual scripts by hard-coding identifiers in this way otherwise maintenance will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Also check that your browser is supported by the version of your QTP!

Answer (score 1):

Use this structure to be more professional :

for each module you hava make :

- Control Action Call TestCase's Function Library
- TestCase's Function Library : Call Functions(Steps) Library
- Separate Database actions in library
- use ObjectRepository Structure Browser/Page/Objects

and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

There error message is telling you that QTP is unable to identify the Browser as specified by your chosen "title" identifier.

Assuming that the identifying properties for the Browser when at GMail are correct, the most likely reason is that the page has not finished loading before you try to do .Set (so therefore the browser title won't be "Gmail:..." yet).

Identifying the browser in this way is not very flexible. Try something like this instead for browser identification:

```
Browser("application version:=internet explorer 8") 'though I don't really recommend this way of identifying either.
```

With a page-independent way of identifying the browser then you can add a Sync statement after opening the browser:

```
Systemutil.Run "http://www.gmail.com"
Browser("application version:=internet explorer 8").Sync
Browser("application version:=internet explorer 8").Page("title:=Gmail.*").WebEdit("name:=Email").Set "xxxxxx" 'If you want to use "title" as an identifier here it'll probably work fine after the sync.
```

Some other things to check if it's really not a Sync issue:

- Which browser are you using? IE? Go to Tools > Manage Add-ons and check that the "BHOManager Class" from HP is present and enabled.
- Is the Web add-in for QTP loaded and associated with your test? By default you get prompted when QTP loads to choose the add-ins, and in your test you can go to File > Settings > Properties and check "Associated add-ins".

Answer (score 0):

The description you use looks OK (I tried it and it works for me). I would suggest trying to use the *Object Spy* tool to confirm that QTP is injected into the browser correctly and that your description matches that of the existing browser.